# I can't open a Visual Studio project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I extracted the zip file of a Visual Studio project that was sent to me, but I can't open it. It says:
`An error occurred in '<MiscFiles>' while attempting to open 'dbo.users [Data]'`

Our VS project is connected with database, so I think it's getting an error opening the database??? Do you guys know how to open a Visual Studio project that is connected to the Microsoft SQL server?

I'd appreciate it a lot, thanks!

This is what's happening:

[image]

Comment: We really can't help you with out seeing the code that actually produces that error also please don't post images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: is it true though? i'm so sorry! thanks for letting me know!

Comment: that doesn't look like a valid filename `dbo.user[Data]` are you sure this is a file?